# Store data dynamically after reading from a file

Tags: c, json, csv

I am trying to read strings from a file separated by commas, and want to display and save the result into a particular format (which looks like a JSON format) during output.

I managed to read and display data from a file but failed to dynamically display it in a format which looks like the example below. Instead, it just displays the entire string in one line before ending.

e.g.

**Contents of the file:**
Distance, 50km, Time, 2 hrs, Date, 1 Jan 2015, etc.

**Desired output result:**

```
{"Distance":"50km"}
{"Time":"2hrs"}  
{"Date":"1 Jan 2015"}
```

**Actual Output**
{" Entire contents from the file " : " nothing appears here "}

I've commented out the lines that deals with reading the file contents until it finds a comma, and where it prints the result in the desired format as those lines didn't work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{     
  if ( argc != 2 )
  {    printf( "Insert filename you wish to open\n Eg: %s filename\n\n", argv[0] );
  }
 else
   {
    FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

    if ( file == 0 )
    {
        printf( "There was an error opening the file\n\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        char a,b;
        while  ( ( a = fgetc( file ) ) != EOF )
        {
            printf( "%c", a,b );
//fscanf(file,"%[^,]",a);/* Read data until a comma is detected,  */
// printf("\nData from file:\n{\"%s\" : \"%s\"}\n\n",a,b); /* Display results into {"A":"B"} format */
        }
        fclose( file );
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
char a[50], b[50];
while(1 == fscanf(file," %[^,]",a) ) /* Read data until a comma is detected,  */
{
  fgetc( file ); // Ignore , character
  fscanf(file," %[^,]",b); /* Read data until a comma is detected,  */
  fgetc( file ); // Ignore , character
  printf("{\"%s\":\"%s\"}\n",a,b); /* Display results into {"A":"B"} format */
}
```

[Live demo here](http://ideone.com/LFS69E)

Note the extra space before format in `fscanf`

The algorithm to read is:

```
while( is reading [a] succesful )
{
  ignore comma
  read [b]
  ignore comma
  print {"a": "b"}
}
```